# Not able to mock ngrx store in angular playground using any mock framework

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use angular playground where i can use common mock data with unit test cases but i am not able to do the following

- Mock NgRx store in Angular Playground sandbox scenerios using
  TS-mockito
- Not able to create common mock data for unit
  testing(Karma) and angular playground. Is it possible?

Can you please advise on this?

Comment: use its mocking https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do when I'm making a sandbox for a component that relies on ngrx store:

```
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

const initialState = {
// put here what the state should look like for this sandbox
}


const sandboxConfig = {
  imports: [
    // module imports for the sandbox
  ],
  declarations: [TheSandboxedComponent],
  exports: [TheSandboxedComponent],
  label: 'Component with ngrx mock store',
};


export default sandboxOf(TheSandboxedComponent, sandboxConfig)
  .add('Default', {
    // The template for the sandbox, adjust to your component
    template: '<my-component></my-component>',
    styles: [],
    providers: [
      // !!! Provide the mock ngrx store here, using the initialState 
      // defined above
      provideMockStore({ initialState: initialState }),
    ],
  })
```

The key is to use ngrx **provideMockStore()**. Please check https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-a-mock-store and the MockStore class documentation for more things you can do such as mocking selectors, actions, etc...